# Is it possible to scrape HTML tables using scrapy shell based on text criteria?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am dipping my fingers in webscraping, and I am trying to scrape the [Queensland Lobbyist Registers](https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists-full-list) and the links within the main register using Scrapy. Each lobbyist has a link that can be followed to get their clientele list (for example, [Antinomies](https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Antinomies) and [Australian Public Affairs](https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists3/Australian-Public-Affairs); however, these nested tables are not consistent within each page.
For Antimonies, for example, the xpath for clients is `//[@id="main"]/table[7]`, and it starts at row 20, and for the APF*, it's `//*[@id="main"]/table[6]`, and starts at row 24. The common thing is that both client subtables come under this row:

***"Client/s on whose behalf lobbying activity is, or may be, conducted"***

Is there a way that Scrapy can be coded to read rows only after specific rows for each page?

I have been using the following:

`tableclients = response.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/table[7]//tbody')
rowclients = tableclients.xpath('//tr')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it's possible to scrape HTML tables using scrapy  based on text criteria which is mostlikely: `Client/s on whose behalf lobbying activity is, or may be, conducted`. Select `h2` tag with it's text node value using `contains()` method and find the preceding-sibling which is table no:7 and from here you have to grab the desired data.

**An example with working code:**

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    custom_settings = {
        #'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        #'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    
    def start_requests(self):
    
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists-full-list',
            callback=self.parse,
            #dont_filter=True
            )
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for Lobbyist in response.xpath('//*[@id="table01546"]/tbody//tr/td[3]/a/@href'):
            link = Lobbyist.get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=link,
                callback = self.parse_client_data,
                
            )
    def parse_client_data(self, response):
        for tr in response.xpath('(//*[contains(text(),"Returns")]/preceding-sibling::table)[7]/tbody//tr'):
            td1 = ''.join(tr.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').getall()).replace(':','').strip().replace('\xa0','')
            td2 = tr.xpath('.//td[2]//text()')
            td2= ''.join(td2.getall()).strip().replace('\xa0',' ') if td2 else None
            yield {td1: td2}
        
             
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(TestSpider)
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
{'Email Address': 'tara@cmaxadvisory.com.au'}
2022-09-11 22:02:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/CMAX-Communications>
{'ACN/ ABN': '73 130 740 546'}
2022-09-11 22:02:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/CMAX-Communications>
{'Trading Name': 'CMAX Advisory'}
2022-09-11 22:02:25 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd> (referer: https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists-full-list)
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'Company Name': 'Counsel House Pty Ltd'}
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'CompanyAddress': 'Level 14, 333 Collins Street, Melbourne VIC 3000'}
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'Phone Number': '03 8639 5890'}
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'Email Address': 'info@counselhouse.com.au'}
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'ACN/ ABN': '35 631 919 009'}
2022-09-11 22:02:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/counsel-house-pty-ltd>
{'Trading Name': 'Counsel House Pty Ltd'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists> (referer: https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists-full-list)
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'Company Name': 'Australian Society of Ophthalmologists'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'CompanyAddress': '6/183 Wickham Terrace, Brisbane QLD 4000'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'Phone Number': '07 383103006'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'Email Address': 'info@asoeye.org'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'ACN/ ABN': '29 454 001 424'}
2022-09-11 22:02:28 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.parliament.act.gov.au/function/tru/act-register-of-lobbyists/act-register-of-lobbyists4/Australian-Society-of-Ophthalmologists>
{'Trading Name': 'Australian Society of Ophthalmologists'}

 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 52,
 
 'item_scraped_count': 255,
```

... so on

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your help. A couple of quick questions:

1. Your code uses a preceding sibling for Returns, and it prints out the first table (Lobbyist information). If I want to print the clients, do I need to use following sibling with the text criteria?

2. Is there a way for the code to look into the links in the main page alphabetically (from top to bottom)?

Comment: See the above update. It will extract client table

Comment: Hope, it will help you cause  I invested a bit more time on it

Comment: @Greation,,Yes, You can grab client table or anyone of the tables or all the tables upto (1 to 7). If you want to get client table just wrap the xpath expession with parenthesis then put index number like:`response.xpath('(//*[contains(text(),"Returns")]/preceding-sibling::table)[7]`. Or remove paranthesis and index to grabl all tables data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`//h3[contains(text(), 'Your text')]/following-sibling::div[1]/text()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).